# How to insert data into two table, while one depends of primary key of other

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm no expert at SQL, just know some nesseary basics, but I need to refactor my LINQ code into SPROCs for better perfomance andI have this scenario.
I have Two tables Threads and Posts.

While I'm creating Thread I also need to create post. It's one-to-many relationship (one Thread may have many posts). But while creating thread I have no way of know what ID thread will have becaause it's autogenerated Identity.

I thought I cloud simply first create thread and later Select last added thread, but How can I be sure it will be exactly the thread I want ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Read the following article [@@IDENTITY vs SCOPE_IDENTITY() vs IDENT_CURRENT – Retrieve Last Inserted Identity of Record](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can call SCOPE_IDENTITY() after your first INSERT. It will get the last Identity value generated. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use trigger. Once you create the thread in the insert trigger you can create a post entry.